# Nodejs: Writing a lot of files: createWriteStream or writeFile?

Tags: node.js, file-io, stream, fs

I have to write a lot of files and I'm wondering which method suits best. The data are text.

I'm a bit concerned on how I can close properly the operation. `createWriteStream` has a `end()` method or `fs.close()`, which closes the stream; `writeFile` has no such method if I well-understood, which may be inefficient after a long batch of write. All the examples of fs.writeFile never mention `fs.close()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`writeFile` doesn't need a `close` method because it opens/writes/closes the file all in a single call.

The main criteria do decide between the two is not the presence/need of an explicit `close` but rather: does the data fit easily in RAM? If it does, then `writeFile` is certainly simpler to use (and potentially a slightly bit faster); else, you better use streams and write data in chunks.

Answer (score 2):

`fs.close()` is actually used to close a file descriptor optained from `fs.open()` or similar functions. What you might be looking at it is `writeable.close()`. `fs.write()` will fully write and finish a file in a single call.

For writing streams, you must close them when finished writing unless you use `readable.pipe()`. The main difference between `fs.createReadStream()` and `fs.writeFile()` is that one accepts a stream and one accepts a in-memory resource. Therefore if you have a large file, it is best to use a stream so only small chunks are loading into memory at one time.